# Laravel 4 -- filtering a collection

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have the following result set in a variable `$types`; and I have a second variable `$typeid` which currently have the value `11`.

```
[
    {"_id":"54077696dee5bd6ce0000029","typeID":"2","type":"road"},
    {"_id":"54077696dee5bd6ce000002a","typeID":"3","type":"street"},
    {"_id":"54077696dee5bd6ce000002b","typeID":"4","type":"avenue"},
    {"_id":"54077696dee5bd6ce000002c","typeID":"5","type":"place"},
    {"_id":"54077696dee5bd6ce000002d","typeID":"6","type":"drive"},
    {"_id":"54077696dee5bd6ce000002e","typeID":"7","type":"way"},
    {"_id":"54077696dee5bd6ce000002f","typeID":"8","type":"blvd"},
    {"_id":"54077696dee5bd6ce0000030","typeID":"9","type":"court"},
    {"_id":"54077696dee5bd6ce0000031","typeID":"10","type":"lane"},
    {"_id":"54077696dee5bd6ce0000032","typeID":"11","type":"mile"}
]
```

I would like to retrieve the corresponding `type` (`mile`) without using a `@for loop`. I tried to use the following:

```
{{ 
    $types->filter(function($t) use ($typeid) { 
        return $t->typeID == $typeid; 
    })->type 
}}
```

But I get the error:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$type
```

Because `$types->filter(function($t) use($typeid) { return $t->typeID == $typeid; })` returns the following (I think `"9"` is the index in the array above ... there's no guarantee the records will maintain the order given):

```
{"9":{"_id":"54077696dee5bd6ce0000032","typeID":"11","type":"mile"}}
```

I was expecting `{"_id":"54077696dee5bd6ce0000032","typeID":"11","type":"mile"}`. Is there a way to rewrite the `->filter` method so that it can return:

```
{"_id":"54077696dee5bd6ce0000032","typeID":"11","type":"mile"}
//or
[{"_id":"54077696dee5bd6ce0000032","typeID":"11","type":"mile"}]  //?
```

Or, is there a way to write the line so that I get the desired result: **start with 11 for example and get mile.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a note in the docs that hadn't made sense until just now:

> **Note**: When filtering a collection and converting it to JSON, try
>   calling the values function first to reset the array's keys.

Therefore re-writing the line as follows solves the problem:

```
{{ 
    $types->filter(function($t) use ($typeid) { 
        return $t->typeID == $typeid; 
    })->values()[0]->type 
}}
```

Since the value of `$types->filter(function($t) use ($typeid) { return $t->typeID == $typeid; })->values()` is:

```
[{"_id":"54077696dee5bd6ce0000032","typeID":"11","type":"mile"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how you're querying for the collection, it's hard to say. Let's assume that you're using an Eloquent model called Type. The best way to do this would be to create a query scope in your model.

```
$types = Type::ofTypeId($typeid)->get();
```

In your model, you'd add the function:

```
public function scopeOfTypeId($query, $typeid)
{
    return $query->whereTypeID($typeid);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I am trying to manipulate the result set in a view, and do not wish to run a query for each value of `typeid` that I am putting in a HTML table.